# Micro Collection of Routes with handler not matched

Tags: phalcon, phalcon-routing

What I am trying to accomplish is the following

```
$collection = new Phalcon\Mvc\Micro();
$collection->setHandler(new \app\Controllers\Brands());
$collection->setPrefix('api/brands');
$collection->get('','actionIndex');
$collection->post('/search','actionSearch');
$collection->get('/{id:[0-9]+}','resourceGet');
$collection->put('/{id:[0-9]+}','resourcePut');
$collection->delete('/{id:[0-9]+}','resourceDelete');

$app->mount($collection);
```

However **no route is matched when going through it's URI** as `www.domain.com/api/brands/search`, but the odd thing here is that **the app itself can handle the routes if specified on the script** as

```
$app->handle('api/brands/search');
```

A **quick and dirty fix** for this would be the following

```
$app->handle(substr($_GET['_url'], 1));
```

but I would like to know if there's a better way to solve it.

Any suggestion or answer is highly appreciated! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the base uri and make sure your routes start with `'/'`. That's the most common problem. Since you are using micro, I guess you don't need to worry about `setBaseUri()` because it's not used in your app.

```
$di->set('url', function(){
    $url = new Phalcon\Mvc\Url();
    $url->setBaseUri('/');
    return $url;
});

$collection->setPrefix('/api/brands');
```

Comment: I can't believe I've been going around this thing for so long... I even wrote tests for the freaking router class... Thank you Ian..

Comment: I know man, Phalcon is a pain to debug, but hey – there's an opportunity to learn C by example :)